# Android: Intent with parameters

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

To pass parameters from one activity to another is used the method "intent.putExtra()"

Does this method only allows to add primitive data  or I can add a parameter that is a java bean?

if you can not, how I can send a java bean from one activity to another?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the API entry for [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).  You've got a load of possible data types you can enter, not the least of which is [Parcebles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), [Bundles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html), and [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html).  If you really want simple object marshalling I would convert your beans to JSON and put it as a String, then convert it back to a POJO on the receiving end.

Answer (score 3):

You can send objects if they implements serializable.

//At your entity Object:

```
public class Objeto implements Serializable{

}
```

//At the sender Activity:

```
 //create an instance of the object
Objeto object = new Objeto();
//creates an intent from the current activity to the destiny activity with the data to be     transferred.
Intent proximo = new Intent(this,TelaDestino.class); 
//transfers the object as a bundle to the next activity
proximo.putExtra("OBJETO",objeto);  
startActivity(proximo);
```

//At the destine activity:

```
private Objeto objeto;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

objeto = (Objeto)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("OBJETO");

}
```

//You can use that and be happy :D

Answer (score 1):

If your object is is Serializable you can add it with putExtra like this.

`i.putExtra(String key, Serializable value);`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to share data between activities is extend the application class.

My answer explains how to use it.

[getApplicaiton return which object among applicaitons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816974/getapplicaiton-return-which-object-among-applicaitons/7817045#7817045)